# How to make option group dynamic in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I’m struggling with this section of code and hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Currently the options are hard coded but I want to make the selection dynamic as I’d like the user to be able to create their own folders later on.

The system is working fine at the moment but I just need this last part to be dynamic for me to be happy with it. I want to loop through the gallery options in the database rather than hard coding.

**Hard coded options:**

```
$photo_form  = '<form id="photo_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php_parsers/photo_system.php">';
$photo_form .=   '<b>Choose Gallery:</b> ';
$photo_form .=   '<select name="gallery" required>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value=""></option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Myself">Myself</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Family">Family</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Pets">Pets</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Friends">Friends</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Random">Random</option>';
$photo_form .=   '</select>';
$photo_form .=   ' &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>Choose Photo:</b> ';
$photo_form .=   '<input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" required>';
$photo_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload Photo Now"></p>';
$photo_form .= '</form>';
```

**My attempt at making the options dynamic, looping:**

```
$photo_form = '<select name="gallery">'
                <?php 
                    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT gal_id, name FROM galleries");
                    while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                        $album_id = $run['gal_id'];
                        $album_name = $run['name'];
                        echo "<option value='$album_id'>$album_name</option>";
                    }
                ?>
```

I can't get it to work no matter what I do, can someone help?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You're not checking if the query was successful, that's very bad idea.

Comment: **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: In your attempt, why do you have another PHP opening tag inside the PHP code? You haven't echo the `select` tag and suddenly you start to echo the options.

Comment: The error is syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: @Solano That is usually because you put HTML in your PHP or you left off an end quote for a string containing HTML. Start from where the error occurs and work backwards.

Comment: Of course, you had the PHP opening tag in PHP mode, that's nonsense. I have fixed your code already. But that's completely unrelated to your problem with dynamic options.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy You shouldn't fix code by editing the question. That's the problem he needed a solution to, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$photo_form .= '<select name="gallery">';          
if ($query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT gal_id, name FROM galleries"))
{
    while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $album_id = $run['gal_id'];
        $album_name = $run['name'];
        $photo_form .= "<option value='$album_id'>$album_name</option>";
    }
}
else {
    error_log(mysqli_error(), 0);

    $photo_form .= '<option>No Records</option>';
}
$photo_form .= '</select>'
echo $photo_form;
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't teach him to not check if the query was successful.

Comment: I hope it was just a joke. You just added another function which works with a result set. But if the query is not successful, you won't get any result set, but `false` instead, so you would end up with an error. Let me edit it.

Comment: Im not sure why you felt the need to edit this when my example basically was the exact same thing. On top of that you are not echo'ing any `<option></option>` on fail which would end in a `Select` with no `Option`

Comment: Sorry, it was the same thing as what? Regarding to the output on error it's purely on him, what he want to show in the case of error. My point was to handle the error state properly (to not crash the script on query error).

Comment: Great, so after your edit, his next Stack Overflow question will be why is his code producing "No Records" when he has a lot of data in a table. And he'll learn that he has to check the query errors (i.e. what you just removed).

Comment: If he sees a No Records then obviously there is either a) an error OR b) no records... If he knows he has records in the table (b) then obviously (a) is the issue and he can print out the errors in a testing environment.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, you've helped me a lot

Comment: lol no problem @DawidFerenczy and I got on a little rant there ;)

Comment: He wasn't able to find the error of the misplaced PHP opening tag even when he had pretty clear error message. Do you think he'll know how to find out the database error?